# CheckedChanged event not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a person entering their address into a form. Then I have a second section on the form that may or may not use their same address they typed. I want a CheckBox that if checked, will fill in their already typed address. However I cannot get it to work. I am using VB.Net. I've tried `.Text` as well as `.ToString()` but either way isn't working.

```
Protected Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox.Checked Then
        TextBoxAddressLine1Work.Text = TextBoxAddressLine1Local.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seems ok. What you mean by "not working"?

Comment: When I click the checkbox to check it or uncheck it,  the text doesn't ever appear

Comment: Check your code (html), maybe value of `TextBoxAddressLine1Local` was reset somewhere between `CheckedChange` event and page rendering. And making server call only for copy value to another control seems a little bid overkill for me. Do it in javascript

Comment: Hm okay I will check. I do notice if I remove the If Statement and just have TextBoxAddressLine1Work.Text = TextBoxAddressLine1Local.Text, then it works when I check the box. (It fills in the text in the textbox) However when I uncheck the box, the text remains in the textbox even though it should no longer be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two conditions for CheckedChanged event to work

1. This event does not post the page back to the server unless the AutoPostBack property is set to true.
2. A CheckBox control must persist some values between posts to the server for this event to work correctly. Be sure that view state is enabled for this control.

The chances are that you may not have the **AutoPostBack** property set to **true**, if it is not then set it as in the following example

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Additional recommendation: *DO NOT use keywords as your identifiers* such as variable name, control ID e.g. you have given assigned "CheckBox" as ID to a CheckBox control in your given example. Such naming convention can cause exceptions which may be hard to trace.

Comment: This worked. I changed AutoPostBack to true and also ViewStateMode to enabled. Thank you!